# How does a nearsighted person see a "magnified image" of a window screen from ten feet away?

Tags: optics, diffraction

This is a direct observation, which many readers can repeat themselves.  If you're a nearsighted person, then without glasses or contact lenses, look at a distant light (a solar powered white LED garden light in this instance) through a large black window screen.

When your eyes are very close to the window screen, the dark lines are of course directly visible.  The distant light is a blurry circle with various streaks and aberrations depending on the state of your cornea.  Although the distant light is not *really* a big blob, the window screen nonetheless appears to block it because it is in focus.

Back away, and the window screen squares don't seem to get smaller or blurrier!  They still block out the blurred light in a grid pattern.  However, at several feet of distance they become *white* lines instead of dark across the blur, with bright white dots at the intersections.  I assume that much is some diffraction effect similar to an Airy disk.  Small motions from side to side make the window screen squares seem to move faster because the distance from where one aligns with the center of the light to where the next aligns is smaller.

I was ten feet away from the window screen, with the pattern dark again, and still able to see the individual lines of the screen as large as if I were standing right next to it, as if nearsightedness were a telescope - a person with good vision would have a hard time making out the squares at that distance.

I suspected that this is related to a diffraction grating and that the "window screen" I see was not going to be usable as an image of the real window screen - at least without advanced signal processing... however, somehow the screen ended up with a nick in it, and the dead end and distortion of that individual square was visible at arm's length, magnified many times from the original!  I suppose the effect can't really be used in astronomy since one planet or star is never "blurry" compared to the next, but are there any interesting applications?

By request: by "black window screen" I mean, in this case, a black plastic grid of small fibers meant to keep flies out, mounted flat in a window.  It is similar to mosquito netting but somewhat coarser, though it works well enough keeping them out in the U.S.  See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Window_with_insect_screen.JPG for example.

Comment: Could you show a picture of the "black window screen"? I can't seem to understand what this is about, and what squares it has.

Comment: Does "black window screen" mean [mosquito net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito_net)?